# PC hang-up 30min after boot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ssd

Let me start with my specs:

```
OS:
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
64-bit

GNOME:
3.28.2

PC:
cpu: Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E5-2698 v3 @ 2.30GHz × 32
memory: 64GB
gpu: NVS 310/PCIe/SSE2 (display) + 2x Nvidia GTX 1070 (for CUDA)
OS on a 256GB SSD
Data on another 1TB SSD
```

**Issue:**

When I boot my PC, it hangs-up after some time, between 10min and 60min. It just stops working, then after 1-2min, it reboots. After that everything is fine. I tend to leave my PC running to avoid being interrupted by a reboot after 1h of working on sth...

Does anyone have a tip for these issues?

*Thanks in advance Best, Alex*

---

To increase chances for a solution (as I expect this issue not to be too common) I posted the same question on other platforms (in german):

[ubuntuforums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2435626)

[ubuntu-forum.de](http://www.ubuntu-forum.de/artikel/67947/1-pc-h%C3%A4ngt-sich-ca-30min-nach-dem-hochfahren-auf-2-gui-eines-programmes-nur-durch-alt-dr%C3%BCcken-aktivierbar-old-title-pc-hang-up-30min-after-boot-problems-with-gui-solved-by-alt-button.html#post400211)

Comment: Check /var/log/ and specific the last updated files in there for messages that contain CRITICAL intermittent crash reboot

Comment: `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` (read `man journalctl`) will show you the end of the logs for the previous boot. They may help.

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks, I will check this the next time it happens

Comment: @waltinator The next time it happens I will check the log, thanks